# How to install a python package into a subdirectory with setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging

I'm trying to make a 3rd party project installable via `pip`. The source repo is currently laid out
like this

```
/plugins
/python
  /foo
    __init__.py
```

The `foo` package is the one that needs to be importable. The project wasn't initially designed to be `pip`-installable, so it expects the `plugins` directory to be installed with the same relative depth as the source repo (2 levels up)

I added a `setup.py` that will install `foo`, but it just gets installed into `Lib/site-packages` as `Lib/site-packages/foo`. Unfortunately, I have no way to install `plugins` to `Lib/plugins` to maintain the same relative `plugins` directory location, and even if I could, I don't think I would want to install to a general location like that.

I'd prefer to install the package and plugins into a subdirectory inside `Lib/site-packages`, so that it looks something like this

```
/Lib
  /site-packages
    /foo-prefix-dir
      /plugins
      /python
        /foo
          __init__.py
```

The `/foo-prefix-dir/python` directory is what would get added to PYTHONPATH, probably using a .pth file, so that `foo` is still importable with the correct relative relation to the `plugins` directory.

Is there any way to distribute a python package this way?

Comment: No, packages are always installed into `site-packages`. If you need to have extra directories — make them part of your package.

Comment: @phd That hasn't always been true. The old python eggs and `easy_install` used to install a little closer to what I want, it would have been `/Lib/site-packages/foo-0.1.0/foo` and then that `foo-0.1.0` directory would get added to an `easy_install.pth` inside the site-packages directory.

Comment: You say you've added at `setup.py`, so you can actually modify the package to be however you want? Why not rearrange the structure so plugins are inside `foo`, and get rid of `python`.

Comment: @blueteeth I may end up doing that, but it would be a hard fork at that point, which I was trying to avoid. This is an upstream project that I don't control.